# C network programing bug because of a \n

Tags: c, sockets, unix, network-programming

I was trying a piece of code in my network lab and I had a strange problem. The code wasn't working because of a **\n**. I am writing the code here:

```
int main()
{
    int sockid;
    char sbuff[50];
    int conn_id,c;
    struct sockaddr_in serv_addr;
    sockid=socket(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM,0);
    printf("socket created");
    memset(sbuff,'0',sizeof(sbuff));
    memset(&serv_addr,'0',sizeof(serv_addr));
    serv_addr.sin_family=AF_INET;
    serv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr=htonl(INADDR_ANY);
    serv_addr.sin_port=htons(4242);

    bind(sockid,(struct sockaddr *)&serv_addr,sizeof(serv_addr));

    if( listen(sockid,5)==-1)
    {
        printf("too many connections try again later");
        return -1;
    }

    while(1)
    {
        conn_id=accept(sockid,(struct sockaddr*)NULL,NULL);
        strcpy(sbuff,"msg from server");
        write(conn_id,sbuff,strlen(sbuff));
        close(conn_id);
    }
    return 1;
}
```

This code doesn't work but instead if I write:

```
printf("socket created \n");
```

in place of:

```
printf("socket created");
```

it works well. Please tell me why is it happening?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read the [About] page soon. You're a bit short on the error checking, aren't you? You do check the `listen()` call; that's good. But there are at least 4 other system calls that should also be checked.  Your `memset()` calls are missing a backslash: `'0'` is very different from `'\0'`. However, it is not obvious how the newline in the `printf()` would make things behave differently.

Comment: What do you mean by "not working"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
printf("socket created");
```

Will not be printed until the stdout buffer is flushed. One way to flush the buffer is with a newline \n. That is why

```
printf("socket created\n");
```

gets printed. So, the problem is not with your printf, but somewhere past that point.

As Jon said, checking your system call return values for error conditions will help you find the problem.

Comment: This is correct. Also, you can force the buffer to be flushed (ie. the text to be printed to the screen) by calling `fflush(stdout)`.